# How to clear Recent Actions panel on Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, reset

How would I go about clearing or re-setting the "Recent Actions" Panel in the Django Admin?

I want the admin interface to look like a fresh install.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The "Recent Actions" panel in Django Admin displays [`LogEntry`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py#L23) models. To clear it you would just delete all the objects:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry

LogEntry.objects.all().delete()
```

Comment: Worked a charm. Just for clarification I made sure i wan in the project directory and then ran this from the Django shell. `python manage.py shell` and just typed the above two lines. Worked perfectly once i restarted.

Answer (score 5):

You can clear **Recent Actions of Django Admin**.

First, open **Django Shell** with this command below:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then, copy & paste these 2 lines of code below to **Django Shell** then press **"Enter"**. That's it:

```py
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
LogEntry.objects.all().delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Run in command prompt :  `python manage.py shell`

Then type these lines one by one:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
LogEntry.objects.all().delete()
```

and after excuting these lines type this line inside the shell to exit the shell:

```
exit()
```